# MATLAB parallel computing - playing sound

Tags: matlab, audio

I have got a question about parallel computing in MATLAB and I would appreciate if one could help.

I have a large vector `X` in MATLAB. In a `for` loop, I do some signal processing on a subvector of `X` and send the resultant data to computer speakers to play it (using `sound` command). The code looks something like

```
for i=1:n
    Y = select_subset(X)   % select part of X vector
    Z = do_processing(Y)   % signal processing on Y 
    sound(Z)               % play Z
end
```

The problem is that there is a slight delay in played sound between different iterations.

I want the sound to play continuously, so I believe I should write the code in a way that does signal processing and playing sound in parallel. Could you please advise me how could I do this?

Comment: As `X` doesn't change between iterations, you can just place the selection and processing outside of the loop. I think you should be a bit more specific on your code, and provide a minimal example that replicates the problem.